# T[] stands for array, why not IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

Why does `T[]` stand for array and not `IEnumerable<T>` in C#?

I know that generics were introduced in .NET 2.0. If it was designed from scratch, does it make any sense to map `[]` to array? Actively using LINQ extension methods, I'd prefer to write simple `T[]` instead of bulky `IEnumerable<T>` or explicit `.ToArray()`.

I'm wondering just for academic reasons.

Comment: What's `T[]` in Java, C++, C?

Comment: Why do we use parentheses for function calls?  That's just the way it is... same here.

Comment: An `IEnumerable<T>` is not a `T[]`.  They are different things.  One is an interface, the other is a built-in type (array).  Note that `IEnumerable<T>` does *not* support indexing, whereas an array does.  You might make the case that you could remove arrays from the language entirely, since you have `List<T>`.  I'm sure performance-minded people would protest, tho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T[]` is the standard syntax for arrays for statically-typed C-like languages. If .NET 1.0 had generics, arrays might have used an `Array<T>` type.

At any rate, if `T[]` was used for `IEnumerable<T>` it could only be used in declarations and you wouldn't be able to create one using `new T[] { ... }`. As far as interfaces go, it would make more sense to map it to `IList<T>` since the square brackets imply indexing.

Comment: And the collection is modifiable.

Comment: Technically there's no reason why you couldn't write that, if the compiler was willing to help (e.g. it might make an `Array<T>` or an object of some other "special" type for you) as it does when e.g. you are writing lambdas. Of course this does not make it a good idea.

Comment: A lot of ickiness in .net and C# is traceable to the fact that .net 1.0 didn't have generics; a further amount is traceable to the fact that generic interfaces did not initially support covariance or contravariance.  The absurd amount of stuff in the smallest standard interface that supports subscripting (i.e. IList<T>) not only poses a headache for implementers--it also means there's no standard covariant interface that can read items by subscript.  Of course, if I had my druthers there would also be a pre-defined 'primitives' for immutable arrays for any type--not just 'char'.